High Connection on Specific Pod in GCP Using Pekko HTTP 1.0.0 Behind Nginx Ingress
I am experiencing an issue in a specific GCP region where the http_server_connection_open_bucket metric from Kamon shows a significantly high number of connections (1.73K compared to other pods with 200).
The architecture involves a client sending requests to Nginx Ingress, which then forwards these requests to our backend service utilizing Pekko HTTP version 1.0.0. As illustrated in the attached images, only one pod is exhibiting an increase in connections, which seems to correlate with a rise in p99 latency and a spike in CPU and memory usage.

When I execute the command netstat -natu | awk '{print $6}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n on the node itself, the output shows a lower number of connections, similar to what other nodes report. This suggests that the problem may lie within the application rather than the node itself.
Here are the Pekko HTTP configurations I am using:
pekko.http {
  server {
    max-connections = 2048
    pipelining-limit = 16
    request-timeout = 1s
  }
}

I am trying to understand why this issue is occurring specifically with one pod and how to diagnose the underlying cause. Is it possible that the GCP node itself is causing this behavior, or could it be an issue within the application?
Any suggestions on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

I understand an open connection as a new request sent by the client and attended by the server, which makes me think that you have some rule that forwards all the request to that instance. You said pod, are you using a container orchestrator or something similar? Could be possible that there is another layer between nginx and the pod that decides where the request should be forwarded? You also said region, are you talking about different physical locations or you just mean at logical level? Could be possible to provide a diagram of the infra detailing the different layers to reach the server?

We are keeping connections open. Our architecture is fairly simple: the client sends requests to an Nginx Ingress, which then forwards them to a Kubernetes service, and finally to a Kubernetes pod, using a round-robin load-balancing strategy. When I mentioned "region," I was referring to different physical locations, not just logical layers.
